# About scrapy's concurrency model

Tags: scrapy

Now I plan to use scrapy in a more distributed approach, and I'm not 
sure if the spiders/pipelines/downloaders/schedulers and engine are 
all hosted in separate processes or threads, could anyone share some 
info about this? and could we change the process/thread count for each 
component? I know now there are two settings "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS" and 
"CONCURRENT_ITEMS", they will determine the concurrent threads for 
downloaders and pipelines, right? and if I want to deploy spiders/ 
pipelines/downloaders in different machines, I need to serialize the 
items/requests/responses, right? 
Appreciate very much for your helps!!

Thanks, 
Edward.

Answer (score 4):

Scrapy is single threaded. It uses the [Reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) to achieve concurrent network requests. This is done using the [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) Framework.

People wanting to distribute Scrapy usually try to implement some messaging framework. Some [use Redis](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis), some others [try RabbitMQ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scrapy-users/-AwGaWBuwyI)

Also have a look at [Scrapyd](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html)